# Firebase issue - no response from Realtime database on iPod with iOS 8.3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ipod, ios8.3

I'm developing an iOS app written in ***Swift*** 3.0 using *Xcode 8.2*, which supports *iOS 8.0 and higher*. App's data is stored in **Firebase**.
I want to listen to database connection changes (app is connected to Firebase or not).
I'm using `FIRDatabaseReference`'s function:

> func observe(_ eventType: FIRDataEventType, with block: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Swift.Void, withCancel cancelBlock: ((Error) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) -> UInt

to observe changes, but this event always returns false (value of 0). At this time (on Firebase Console), `Authentication` section related queries are working properly, and `Realtime Database` related queries are not.
**This happens only** on iPod 5.1 (5) with iOS 8.3.

I've tested my application on

- iPad 2 with iOS 8.4.1
- iPod 5.1 (5) with iOS 9.3.5
- iPhone 6 with iOS 10.0.1

too. But on these devices it worked well.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any issue related to iOS version and Firebase SDK?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I left this issue a little bit behind, and after some time, it reappeared on another device.

I'm not sure, if this solves every similar problem, but I figured out, that ***my token was expired*** and I get ***NO response from database***. Which problem was caused by a password change of the same user on another device.

*Day 1* - I was logged in with an account on two different devices. I changed my password on one of them.

*Day 2* - I tried to download some data from `Realtime Database` section with the other device, but I get *NO response*, which was really annoying.

After 8 hours Firebase Analytics logs on Xcode console finally helped me figure out the problem. I logged out from the problematic device, and then logged in again.

I was wondering why couldn't I get some kind of 'token_expired'-response from the server, or maybe why couldn't I get logged out from the other devices.